# iTextSharp Read Text From Single Layer of PDF

Tags: pdf, text, itext, layer, extract

Currently I am using a custom LocationTextExtractionStrategy to extract text from a PDF that returns a TextRenderInfo[]. I would like to be able to determine if a TextRenderInfo object (or PDFString, child of TextRenderInfo) appears in a specific layer. I am not sure if this is possible. To get the layers in a PDF, I am using:

```
Dictionary<string,PdfLayer> layers;
using (var pdfReader = new PdfReader(src))
{
    var newSrc = Path.Combine(["new file location"]);
    using (var stream = new FileStream(newSrc, FileMode.Create))
    {       
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, stream);
        layers = stamper.GetPdfLayers();
        stamper.Close();
    }
    pdfReader.Close();
    src = newSrc;
}
```

To extract the text, I am using:

```
var textExtractor = new TextExtractionStrategy();
PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, pdfPageNum,textExtractor);
List<TextRenderInfo> results = textExtractor.Results;
```

Is there any way that I can check if the individual TextRenderInfo results exist within the layers obtained in the first code snippet. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It is surely possible, but before I start answering: you mention in your title that you use iText 7, but your code is quite clearly written in iText 5 (iTextSharp). The APIs are similar, but not identical, so I'll need to know what you want in order to answer your question.

Comment: I apologize, I am using iTextSharp (5), and I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to get the contents from a single layer, but you'll have to jump through a few hoops to work it out. Specifically, you will have to recreate some of the logic that is provided by the `PdfTextExtractor` and `PdfReaderContentParser`.

```
public static String GetText(PdfReader reader, int pageNumber, int streamNumber) {
    var strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
    var processor = new PdfContentStreamProcessor(strategy);

    var resourcesDic = pageDic.GetAsDict(PdfName.RESOURCES);

    // assuming you still need to extract the page bytes
    byte[] contents = GetContentBytesForPageStream(reader, pageNumber, streamNumber);

    processor.ProcessContent(contents, resourcesDic);
    return strategy.GetResultantText();
}

public static byte[] GetContentBytesForPageStream(PdfReader reader, int pageNumber, int streamNumber) {
    PdfDictionary pageDictionary = reader.GetPageN(pageNum);
    PdfObject contentObject = pageDictionary.Get(PdfName.CONTENTS);
    if (contentObject == null)
        return new byte[0];

    byte[] contentBytes = GetContentBytesFromContentObject(contentObject, streamNumber);
    return contentBytes;
}

public static byte[] GetContentBytesFromContentObject(PdfObject contentObject, int streamNumber) {
    // copy-paste logic from
    // ContentByteUtils.GetContentBytesFromContentObject(contentObject);
    // but in case PdfObject.ARRAY: only select the streamNumber you require
}
```

If you're specifically looking to just use `PdfTextExtractor` or `PdfReaderContentParser`, and ask the returned `TextRenderInfo` for the layer it's on, then I'm not sure it will be easily possible. There are a number of problems with that:

- `TextRenderInfo` doesn't store that information, so you'd have to subclass it (which is possible)
- you'd have to rewrite the logic that creates the `TextRenderInfo` objects. This is possible by registering custom `IContentOperator` objects for all text operators (`Tj`, `TJ`, `'` and `"`) with the `PdfTextExtractor` or `PdfReaderContentParser`
- the hardest part is that you have already lost layer information in `ContentByteUtils.GetContentBytesFromContentObject` - so you'd need to retain that somehow, which creates its own set of problems.