# Get Text From specific Layer from PDF

Tags: c#

Here is the pdf sample with texts on the layer. If I turn off the layer all the text belong to this layer will be invisible also.
I need to get all the texts from the specific layer. Any body know how to archive this.

Here is my sample PDF file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TcRyE8MQRhw-j89BbovV7fFIwZ0yks0N/view?usp=sharing

My code can get all texts. But I don't know how to get texts belong any specific layer only.

```
public CreateHyperLinkButton(string inPutPDF, string outPutPDF, List<ViewPortInfo> ViewportInfos)
    {

        using (FileStream pdf = new FileStream(outPutPDF, FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (PdfReader pdfReader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(inPutPDF))
            {
                using (PdfStamper pdfStamper = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper(pdfReader, pdf))
                {
                    //Get Text list on 2D PDF
                    List<TextRenderInfo> listTextInfor = GetAllTextInfor(inPutPDF, pdfReader);

                    listTextInfor.ForEach(item =>{
                        string btnName = item.GetText().Trim();

                        //Check btnName exist in ViewportInfos
                        for (var i = 0; i < ViewportInfos.Count; i++)
                        {
                            string szRes = GetTextContained(ViewportInfos[i].Hyperlinks.Keys.ToList(), btnName);
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(szRes))
                            {
                                iTextSharp.text.Rectangle box = GetRectOfText(item);
                                iTextSharp.text.pdf.PushbuttonField btnField = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PushbuttonField(pdfStamper.Writer, box, szRes);
                                iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfAnnotation pushbutton = btnField.Field;

                                //Add JS function and button in annotation
                                string js = "mapView('" + szRes + "');";
                                pushbutton.SetAdditionalActions(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.U, iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfAction.JavaScript(js, pdfStamper.Writer));
                                pdfStamper.AddAnnotation(pushbutton, 1);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    pdfStamper.Close();
                }
                pdfReader.Close();
            }
            pdf.Close();
        }
    }

    private static List<TextRenderInfo> GetAllTextInfor(string inPutPDF, PdfReader pdfReader)
    {
        List<TextRenderInfo> listTextInfor = new List<TextRenderInfo>();

        TextExtractionStrategy allTextInfo = new TextExtractionStrategy();

        for (int i = 1; i <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, i, allTextInfo);
        }
        listTextInfor = allTextInfo.textList;
        return listTextInfor;
    }

public class TextExtractionStrategy : ITextExtractionStrategy
{
    public List<TextRenderInfo> textList = new List<TextRenderInfo>();
    public void BeginTextBlock()
    {

    }

    public void EndTextBlock()
    {

    }

    public string GetResultantText()
    {
        return "";
    }

    public void RenderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        var a = renderInfo;
    }

    public void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        textList.Add(renderInfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some more information, code and details that will help others understand what you've done and give them more context.

Comment: I revised the question as above. I would like to get list of text from specific layer and add button on that layer. Welcome with any methods and free library.

Comment: have you checked this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49272379/1566339 it uses iTextSharp, and I've just tried on your PDF, and it, apparently retrieves all the content.

Comment: Hi André Lemos, On that solution I didn't see where is layer. In my PDF sample file, I would like to get all texts belong layer named "X1|A-AREA-____-IDEN".

Answer (score -2):

You could use [ironpdf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IronPdf/) for this purpose. Parse/open the pdf as per the docs on their site and examine it in debug, then you can develop some code to retrieve text from that layer only.

Comment: I would need the pdf for this. What you should try is check the contents of the Pdf variable in debug very thoroughly and try to dig out how layers are managed and act on that.

Comment: Here is my PDF file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TcRyE8MQRhw-j89BbovV7fFIwZ0yks0N/view?usp=sharing

I get exception when I try extract some text as below:
Unable to cast object of type 'PdfSharp.Pdf.<97775c1b-0c5a-4ffb-a824-3bad0a901470>PdfName' to type 'PdfSharp.Pdf.<5a452451-a2fc-4726-b1d4-e37eac5fbb7f>PdfDictionary'.

Comment: I tried to reproduce, i think this is due to chinese characters